#  Can not run Primefaces showcase webapp

Tags: eclipse, jsf, maven, primefaces, mojarra

I have downloaded Primefaces form http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/sou ... 2Fshowcase. 
I did cd showcase/ 
mvn clean install -Pmojarra 
mvn eclipse:eclipse

Primefaces 3.2-SNAPSHOT and Mojarra 2.1.4 are used when used mojarra profile to build Primefaces Showcase webapp

then I run showcase webapp on server (Tomcat 6, I also tested Tomcat 7) but I am getting following exception

```
EVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:305)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:360)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: org.primefaces.examples.application.ShowcaseExceptionHandlerFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:603)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:482)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:138)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:959)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:316)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:303)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.examples.application.ShowcaseExceptionHandlerFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:591)
    ... 23 more
Feb 21, 2012 3:19:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:305)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:360)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: org.primefaces.examples.application.ShowcaseExceptionHandlerFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:603)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:482)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:138)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:959)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:316)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:303)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.examples.application.ShowcaseExceptionHandlerFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:591)
    ... 23 more
Feb 21, 2012 3:19:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Feb 21, 2012 3:19:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/prime-showcase] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 21, 2012 3:19:03 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:967)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:316)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4886)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

I think it is related with my setup environment but I am not able to figure out. I try to search solution of it an one thing I conclude is that it could be because of to different version fo jsf at run time in my eclipse but 
I am not able to find more then one implementation used at runtime. 
Did anyone faced this problem or any one have idea what could be the possible root cause ?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't there more down into the stacktrace? For example a `ClassNotFoundException` or so? The `FacesException` is merely a wrapper exception. The real root cause would be the real answer to your question.

Comment: Hi BalusC, I have edited stcktrace in my main post. Now you can check whole stacktrace.

Comment: OK, thus a CNFE as I initially suspected. If the class is indeed really not present in the showcase app, I'd contact PrimeFaces. Perhaps it's just an oversight. Have you also tried a stable version instead of a snapshot?

Comment: Actually, org.primefaces.examples.application.ShowcaseExceptionHandlerFactory class does exist at proper palce. But I do not know why it is getting this error. I search online and many people says that (I am not suere if this is true in my case) it coulbe mixup of jsf api's i.e. maven jsf is not getting used and defaul jsf is used by eclipse or tomcat at runtime.

Comment: I guess you're running in Eclipse? If you look at the Deploment assembly in your project properties. Are the Maven depenencies there? (Take look here http://quakology.blogspot.nl/2011/10/how-to-enable-maven-for-dynamic-web.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. try to do an update maven.

```
Project > maven > update Project
```